# How to preserve line breaks when writing ArrayList to file with ObjectOutputStream?

Tags: java, arraylist, line-breaks, objectoutputstream

I'm following this [tutorial](https://samderlust.com/dev-blog/java/write-read-arraylist-object-file-java) on how to output an `ArrayList` to a text file with `ObjectOutputStream`, but this removes the line breaks from my original file. In other words, I read a file in, do stuff to it, and write it back out. The data read in remain an ArrayList throughout processing. How do I preserve the line breaks when writing an ArrayList out to file? Do I lose this ability when I read it in as ArrayList?

Comment: That tutorial is about how to *serialize* an `ArrayList` to a *binary* file. Binary files don't have lines or line breaks, and neither do `ArrayLists`. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the tutorial.  `ObjectOutputStream` is not designed for outputting **text** files.  If you try to read a file produced by this class, you will see lots of binary data; i.e. things that show up as unprintable characters or "garbage" if you try to view it as text.

However, `ObjectOutputStream` it will not be explicitly removing line breaks.  It is more likely that the line break characters were removed when you turned your input text into an `ArrayList`.

But that is moot.  If you want to output a text file, don't use `ObjectOutputStream`.  Use a `FileWriter` and iterate the `ArrayList` to output each (erm) line followed by a line break.

---

> Do I lose *[the line breaks]* when I read it in as `ArrayList`?

That depends on *how* your read the input file and populated the `ArrayList`.  (We cannot explain the behavior of your code if you don't show it to us.  We don't even know for sure what the element type for the `ArrayList` is ...)